# Swift: How to address an enumerator using a string variable

Tags: swift, enums

I'm working on an app using AudioKit. This creates a simple, smooth low frequency tone for 1 second:

```
let osc = DynamicOscillator(amplitude: 0)

let audioEngine = AudioEngine()

audioEngine.output = osc

do {

    try audioEngine.start()
                    
    osc.amplitude = 0
    
    osc.start()

} catch {

    print("could not start audioengine")
}

osc.$frequency.ramp(to: frequency, duration: 0.5)

osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: 1, duration: 0.5)

osc.setWaveform(Table(.sine))
    
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {

    osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: 0, duration: 0.5)

}
```

Now I'd like the user to choose what waveform to use. This part:

```
osc.setWaveform(Table(.sine))
```

Needs to be modified to read the waveform from a string variable, like this

```
var waveform = "sine"

osc.setWaveform(Table(waveform))
```

But this does not work, because Table expects an enum. **.sine** comes from an enum called **TableType**, defined like this:

```
public init(_ type: TableType = .sine,
            phase: Float = 0,
            count: IndexDistance = 4096)
{
    self.type = type
    self.phase = phase
    content = [Element](zeros: count)

    switch type {
    case .sine:
        standardSineWave()
    case .sawtooth:
        standardSawtoothWave()

[...]
```

And so on.

How do I address an enum by using a string variable?

Comment: Make the enum have String as raw type and use `init(rawValue: String)` to convert. Or simply add your own function that uses a `switch` to match a string to the correct enum case.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. Could you elaborate a little? I'm new to swift (though not new to progamming). TableType comes from the AudioKit library, I could tamper the lib, yet I guess I don't need to. (I thought about the switch solution, but this will blow up the code, I assume there's a more elegant way)

Comment: If it’s not your enum then use a standalone function to do the conversion. You could make it conform to RawRepresentable in an extension but you still need that switch code